# Find and list duplicates in an unordered array consisting of 10,000,000,00 elements

Tags: java, arrays

How can duplicate elements in an array, that consists of
unordered 10,000,000,00 elements, be determined? How can they be listed?

Please ensure the performance is taken care of while writing the logic of Java code.

What is the space complexity and time complexity of the logic?

Consider an example array, `DuplicateArray[]`, as shown below.

```
String DuplicateArray[] =  {"tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael",
"Bill","HP","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael",
"Bill","HP","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael",
"Agnus","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael",
"Obama","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael",
"Obama","HP","TCS","CTS","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael","rachael","tom","wipro","hcl","Ibm","rachael"}
```

Comment: "Please dont post negative votes for the question i have asked.i think this is atleast a valid question in java". It's a homework question, and you've shown no evidence of the work you've done.

Comment: You need to say if it is an assignment. People may want to answer it differently. And you should have shown what you'd tried so far. If you had done either, you wouldn't have attracted so many negative votes. Also, you don't appear to have upvoted the helpful replies you did get so why do you expect others to be generous?

Comment: ++ what Paul said. I probably shouldn't have voted negatively, but what irked me was his begging not to get negative votes.  Sorry.  I'll do better.

Comment: You're getting negative votes, @Deepak, because this is **not** a valid question in Java.  It's more a "please do my work for me" question or, worse, "please do my homework for me" question.  Paul's answer to your complaint is dead on.  Is this homework?  (I suspect it is.)  What have you tried so far?  What are you doing to make people **want** to answer your question?  (Hint: nothing.)

Comment: ok i got it.i will do some R & D before posting here,Im a newbie to Stack overflow...kindly excuse all.

Comment: Is the list really meant to have one, or ten, billion elements? That's quite a list...

Comment: @David,This was asked in one of biggest IT firms Intws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
class MyValues{
    public int i = 1;
    private String value = null;

    public MyValues(String v){
        value = v;
    }

    int hashCode()
    {
        return value.length;
    }

    boolean equals(Object obj){
        return obj.equals(value);
    }
}
```

Now iterate for duplicates

```
private Set<MyValues> values = new TreeSet<MyValues>();
for(String s : duplicatArray){
    MyValues v = new MyValues(s);
    if (values.add(v))
    {
        v.i++;
    }
}
```

Time and space are both linear.

Comment: @qayamat,whats the time and space complexity in terms of logarthmic complexity,can you elaborate

Comment: Qayamat: Why hand out code for a homework assignment when the OP hasn't yet shown their work?

Comment: @Deepak: please find it urself.

Comment: @Hovercraft : U should stop posting users their homework assignment.

Comment: Actually, time is not linear if you use `TreeSet`.

Comment: Accepted solution,Thanks all for your immensable contribution for this thread

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Set. Best for you will be HashSet. Put your elements to it one by one. And check existence in every insert operation.

Something like this:

```
HashSet<String>hs = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String>Answer = new HashSet<String>();
for(String s: DuplicateArray){
    if(!hs.contains(s))
        hs.add(s);
    else
        Answer.add(s);
}
```

Code depends on the the assumption, that type of elements of your array is String

Comment: @llnur,Thanks.but what about the time complexity and space complexity for your program and will the program work for unordered 10,000,000,00 duplicate elements

Comment: Work it out yourself? How often does it visit each string in the array, and how often does it process a duplicate? What ends up in hs and Answer? And yes, it will work for 10,000,000,000. Might take a while, but as fast as anything else. If the assignment is asking you to consider what happens when hs doesn't fit in memory then that's a slightly different issue.

Comment: Space complexity depends on the count of different elements in your array. If it consist of 1 000 000 000 different elements, it'd be very slow solution. You have to save your elements to some database, I think.

Comment: I think HashSet works faster, than TreeSet (insertion procedure takes log(N) time in TreeSet and O(1) in HashSet, where N - count of elements in Set).

Comment: @Deepak: so, the summary complexity looks like this: O(N) time, O(count of different elements) space with HashSet and O(N*log(N)) time, O(count of different elements) with TreeSet.

Comment: You do have the problem that the Duplicate array cannot have more than 2^31-1 entries, ~ 2 billion. so it cannot be 10 billion.

Answer (score 0):

How many duplicates are expected? A few or comparable to the number of entries or something in between?

Do you know anything else about the values? E.g are they from some specific dictionary?

If not, iterate over the array, build a HashSet, noting when you are about to add an entry that's already there and keeping those in a list. I can't see anything else is going to be faster.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an assignment? It's pretty obvious code, I would have thougt, and if it is an assignment I'm not going to write it for you. Anyway @llnur has done it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you mean 10,000,000,00 as one billion or 10 billion.  If you mean the later, you cannot have more than 2 billion elements in an array or a Set. The suggestions you have so far will not work in this situation. To have 10 billion Strings in memory you will need at least 640 GB and AFAIK, there is not server available which will allow this volume of memory in a single JVM.

For a task this large, you may have to consider a solution which breaks up the work, either across multiple machines or put the work into files to be processed later.

You have to either assume;

- You have a relatively small number of unique Strings. In this case, you can built a Set in memory of the words you have seen so far.  These will fit into memory. (Or you might assume they do)
- Break up the files into manageable sizes.  A simple way to do this would be to write to a few hundred work files based on hashcode.  The hashcode for the same strings will be the same so as you process each file in memory, you know that it will contain all the duplicates, if there are any.